# Is there any provision to develop and expose custom web services from Bizagi platform?

Tags: web-services, bizagi

In one instance my custom mobile app that connects to Bizagi platform has to save data to SAP back-end. Looking for options to implement this.

To avoid having the mobile app interfacing with multiple back-end/platforms, looking for options to achieve this through the Bizagi interface.

It is learned that Bizagi has out of the box connectors for SAP et. to integrate one with other.

Also learned that Bizagi exposes out of the box webservices that extends its features to custom front-end apps.

Along with these out of the box Bizagi webservices, is there any provision in Bizagi to develop and expose custom webservices to pass data from mobile app to back-end systems such as SAP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use several of the methods exposed in the Bizagi API to create cases, trigger events, perform activities, query entities, etc. etc.

The services with which you can affect the flow are exposed in: http://+ (YourServiceURL)+ /+ (NameProyect)+ /WebServices/WorkflowEngineSOA.asmx

The services with which you can affect or query the entities are exposed in: http://+ (YourServiceURL)+ /+ (NameProyect)+ /webservices/EntityManagerSOA.asmx

Also you can consult into the official documentation depending your versión and your needs and look at the request examples for the services

Additionally it has a connection with SAP services through connectors within the tool